# get data from json c#

Tags: c#, json, class

I have a problem I want to get data from Json, and the data 
successfully gets from the json to the variable json but when I want to send the data to WeatherData it send me a zero value.
I have one class that cald "WeatherData" and I want to send to data from the json (that existing a class "jsonParse") to this class.

jsonParse

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace weather
{
    public class jsonParse : Ijson
    {
        private string urlAdd;

        public jsonParse(string _url)
        {
            if (_url == null)
            {
                //throw exption
            }
            else
                urlAdd = _url;
        }

        public WeatherData parse()
        {

            //string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(urlAdd);
            //var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherData>(json);
            //Console.WriteLine(obj.temp);
           // WeatherData m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherData>(json);


                WebClient n = new WebClient();
                var json = n.DownloadString(urlAdd);
                string valueOriginal = Convert.ToString(json);
                WeatherData m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherData>(json);
                Console.WriteLine(m);




                return m;

        }


    }
}
```

WeatherData

```
namespace weather
{
    public class WeatherData
    {

        public WeatherData(double _temp, double _minTemp, double _maxTemp )
        {
            temp = _temp;
            minTemp = _minTemp;
            maxTemp = _maxTemp;

        }

        public double temp { get; set; }
        public double minTemp { get; set; }
        public double maxTemp { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "the weather:" + temp + "minTemp is:" + minTemp + "maxTemp:" + maxTemp;
        }
    }
}
```

json

```
{"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},
"sys":{"country":"JP","sunrise":1369769524,"sunset":1369821049},
"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],
"main":{"temp":289.5,"humidity":89,"pressure":1013,"temp_min":287.04,"temp_max":292.04},
"wind":{"speed":7.31,"deg":187.002},
"rain":{"3h":0},
"clouds":{"all":92},
"dt":1369824698,
"id":1851632,
"name":"Shuzenji",
"cod":200}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about the weather part of the json, try this -

```
        var o = (JArray)JObject.Parse(jsonString)["weather"];
        foreach(JToken item in o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((JValue)item["id"]).Value);
            Console.WriteLine(((JValue)item["main"]).Value);
            Console.WriteLine(((JValue)item["description"]).Value);
            Console.WriteLine(((JValue)item["icon"]).Value);
        }
```

Comment: And if I want main values - temp, min temp and max temp what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

First object in json is coord, don't see that in your model.
You should change your JsonModel to deserialize. From c# class generator:

```
public class Coord
{
    public int lon { get; set; }
    public int lat { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public double temp_min { get; set; }
    public double temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public double deg { get; set; }
}

public class Rain
{
    public int __invalid_name__3h { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Rain rain { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}
```

Where RootObject is your JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
So you can change class names as you like.

Comment: If you want to name properties with your name (not json names) use [JsonProperty"jsonName"]
string yourName;

Comment: do i need to put all of that in "WeatherData"?

Comment: Well with deserializer i think you have to use following properties to your directed one. Mean if you need "country", you have to add class with "sys".  IMO.

Comment: It throws an exception.. why is that?

Comment: What kind of the exception?

Comment: Well i just used classes that i have pasted above and i get result in console:

the weather:289,5minTemp is:287,04maxTemp:292,04

I have to have some name or type errors in model.
Outside that classes i have nothing more than:
            RootObject ro = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            Debug.WriteLine("the weather:" + ro.main.temp + "minTemp is:" + ro.main.temp_min + "maxTemp:" + ro.main.temp_max);

Answer (score 0):

Simply you cannot Deserialize a json object to a non-matching class object. So make sure you have a model object that have atleast all the properties that JSON object have.

In this case you would need following classes that are generated from your JSON object:

```
public class Coord
{
    public int lon { get; set; }
    public int lat { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public double temp_min { get; set; }
    public double temp_max { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public double deg { get; set; }
}

public class Rain
{
    public int __invalid_name__3h { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class ParentModel
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Rain rain { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}

ParentModel m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParentModel>(json);
```

Hope this helps.